# RESTful WCF Service Configuration using PrincipalPermission

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, authorization

I am trying to create a WCF service that uses the PrincipalPermission to validate the calling client is in an AD role.  The service is an internal service, so all callers should be on the domain.  An added caveat is the service response is a file stream.  Also, I would like to use webHttpBinding to make this a RESTful service.  Can all of this be done without forcing the client to enter credentials when calling the service?

```
[OperationContract]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "CanDownloadFilesFromMyService")]
public Stream DownloadFile(int fileId)
{
    return MyOtherCode.GetFile(fileId);
}
```